# No options in Visual Studio for data origins

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

this is me again, sorry for my old bad written questions, but now I just want I few help with something.

I was working with basic project (homework) when I decided to update my Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code, the purple one), and then this happens, for some reason I have no data origins now I said now because yesterday I had data origins, I haven't read Microsoft's info yet, but this question is just in case nothing is found and I have the .net Desktop developer pack installed.

I add an image and thank you for your help and excuse me for my no knowledge about how to ask questions correctly here (english is not my first language and college stuff keeps me busy all the time)

[image]

[image]

What I tried (still not read Microsoft data about this problem)

- Install again Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

This is because you created the wrong project type:

[image]

If the project type I create is Windows Forms App(.NET Framework), the data source can be bound normally.

[image]